# about clang unsequenced warning

Tags: c++, clang

I cannot understand why the following code will generate unsequenced warning when compile with clang

```
int a=2;
a+=a-=2;
```

as a comparison , I can understand the following which also generate the same warning

```
int i=1;
i = i++ + i;
```

since i could be 2 or 3 (operator + is unseqnenced per C++ standard), and the warning makes sense, but for a, it seems it will always be 0 , there is no indetermination, the warning makes no sense. Please help. Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) See this answer in particular for your first case. It's UB before c++17, but valid from c++17.

Comment: Oops, I meant this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46171943/8372853).

Comment: thanks. I updated my clang version to 10.0 and compiled with ```/std:c++17``` which dismissed the warning.